Powering SG90 Servo with 18650 battery
I want to power one SG90 servo with an 18650 3.7v battery. Since the working range for the servo is 4.8v-6v, I used XL6009 boost converter and got a 5.8v output. I have measured it with my multimeter. When I connected everything, it just fried my servo. I tested several of them with my Arduino connected to a 9v battery and they worked fine, but with this setup, they burn.
I tested every component and wire separately for continuity and voltage. The wires I connect to the servo give 5.8v and the PWM wire gives a variable signal as per the "Sweep" example code. The code itself is correct since it works with Arduino connected directly.
What is wrong?
Could anyone suggest an article of book to read regarding this? My distant goal is to create a hexapod with 18 servos powered by 18650.


It is powered by a micro-USB cable from the computer. Schematic is the same as in official docs, except for the XL6009 boost converter - https://docs.arduino.cc/static/9521df5ddacc221dd7560ba80e2acc3e/29114/servo_circuit_knob.png

I tested several of them with my Arduino connected to a 9v battery ... the 9 V battery is not able to provide enough current to burn the servo

I was answering the question that was later deleted. Please, read carefully, with 9v battery it works fine, that's 18650 with boost converter that fried the servo.

read my comment again

As the SG90's maximum voltage rating is 6v, running it at 5.8v can heat it up quite a bit. Even if it worked, running it on 5.8v is not a good long term solution. Your servo probably burned up because of the heat it generated. 5V is pretty much the safe spot for running a SG90 servo.
The servo worked with the arduino and the 9v battery because the arduino has a built-in voltage regulator, and gives a regulated 5v power supply to it's 5v pin (and the I/O) so your servo was getting 5v from the arduino, not anything higher or lower.
I did some research and it says that the lowest output voltage of the xl6009 boost converter is 5v, so see if you could make the voltage lower.
I recommend buying another of the same battery and connecting both together, then using a voltage regulator module to reduce the voltage to 5v.
